# Error in Building FXRuby from Source on Linux

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, fxruby

I encounter an issue in building FXRuby from source. Below are the steps I did.

1. download the source from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=300&release_id=41247, click on FXRuby-1.6.19.tar.gz.
2. extract the file

   $ tar xzf FXRuby-1.6.19.tar.gz
3. follow the instruction in **doc/build.html**

   $ cd FXRuby-1.6.19

   $ ruby install.rb config -- \
    --with-fox-include=/home/sambath/FXRuby-1.6.19/ext/fox16/include --with-fox-lib=/home/sambath/FXRuby-1.6.19/lib/fox16

This is the error message.

```
**********************************************************************
*                            Hey!                                    *
*                    Where is FOX installed?                         *
*                                                                    *
* I couldn't locate 'fxver.h' in any of the following directories:   *
*                                                                    *
*   /home/sambath/FXRuby-1.6.19/ext/fox16/include
*   /usr/include/fox-1.6
*   /usr/local/include/fox-1.6
*   /sw/include/fox-1.6
*   /opt/local/include/fox-1.6
*                                                                    *
* Please specify the locations for the FOX header files and library  *
* using the --with-fox-include and --with-fox-lib options to         *
* extconf.rb as described in the FXRuby installation instructions.   *
**********************************************************************
```

I have checked the directory **/home/sambath/FXRuby-1.6.19/ext/fox16/include**, but I could not find the file the this directory. Where is it located? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sambath, it sounds like you either have not yet installed FOX or that you've installed it in a non-standard location; I'm guessing it's the former. Please see the instructions at https://github.com/lylejohnson/fxruby/wiki/Setting-Up-a-Linux-Build-Environment on how to set up the build environment (including FOX) on an Ubuntu system.